# Is there a way to dynamically generate tables in SQLite based on class definitions?

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlite

I'm using c# and System.Data.SQLite
I have some classes I want to generate as tables in SQLite at runtime, but I don't want to hardcode the SQL string for each class.
I was wondering, what is the best method to do this?
I tried adding attributes to my class and class properties hoping there would be something that would create the SQL string for me but...
Here's an example:

```
  [Table(Name = "tblDocument")]
  public class Document
  {
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public long DocumentId { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
    public string File { get; set; }
  }
```

To create this as a table in SQLite I need to generate something like:

```
  string CreateSqlString =
    @"CREATE TABLE [tblDocument] (" +
    @"[DocumentId] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
    @"[File] TEXT  NOT NULL)";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is a commercial db provider for sqlite that comes with EF/LINQ support which can do what you want... if that is an option for you I can provide a link...

Comment: I thought System.Data.SQLite had support for Entity Framework?
Anyways, what i want may or may not involve EF, I really don't care on the technology used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you maybe looking for something like [SubSonic](http://github.com/subsonic). It can be run with migrations turned on and that will generate tables for your classes.

Assuming you have referenced Castle.Core.dll, SubSonic.Core.dll and System.Data.SQLite.DLL

```
class Program
{
    private const string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=c:\subsonic.db";
    private const string ProviderString = @"System.Data.SQLite";
    private static IDataProvider provider = ProviderFactory.GetProvider(ConnectionString, ProviderString);
    private static SimpleRepository repo = new SimpleRepository(provider, SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var demo = new Demo { Name = "Test Demo", LaunchDate = DateTime.Now };
        repo.Add(demo);
    }

    class Demo
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime LaunchDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

App.config should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
</configuration>
```